# Best way to pass context

Tags: go, go-context

I've done a lot of research regarding context, but I can't seem to find a generally accepted answer, plus I'm new to **Go**.

In my current code I've `var ctx = context.Background()`,which is used in various places.

My concern is, aren't all my code modifying the same context since it's a global variable? .

Yes, I know context is **request scoped**.

This is part of my code for context.

```
var ctx = context.Background()

var db *firestore.Client

var auth *aut.Client

func init() {
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db, err = app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    auth, err = app.Auth(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func SetRate(r int) (err error) {
    //TODO: create last updated field
    _, err = db.Collection("Rate").Doc("rate").Set(ctx, map[string]int{"USDT": r})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Please try not to use overly complicated words to describe a term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its an accepted practice in `go` to pass context from function to function. Normally, the first parameter of every function if `context` type. I have seen that whenever a context is passed down and has some use-case with in the method scope, a new context is created from parent context.

Comment: So, are you saying my current implementation is okay? Cause my whole question is can i use a global context for methods.

Comment: Yes. In general, the main context is created at the entry of the system. be it a rest api request, a command line input or anything. That context is then passed down the system. There may be cases where a new context is required. in that case, new context is created from *passed down* context i.e., `childCtx := context.WithValue(ctx, "key", "value")`. Noew this `childCtx` has scope starting from this given function and `ctx` is the main context.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to create a context inside of a function and pass it between functions as needed, rather than having the one context shared across the package. For something like a HTTP server, you will typically see a unique context for each incoming API call.